# How to load the data whose name starts with 's' in informatica?

Tags: sql, informatica

I have f_name and l_name in the source. I need to load the full name by combining f_name and l_name whose name starts with 's' ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your source is not a db table(If it is a DB table you can directly use a SQL query with a where clause and use it as SQL override in SQ transformation)

Use a filter transformation with following expression in filter condition:

`UPPER(SUBSTR(f_name,1,1))='S'`

Then in a expression trnasformation create a output port with below expression:

`f_name||' '||l_name`